# Multiple select forms with the same Javascript styling

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have two select forms that use the same JS. I want each of them to contain a list of colours that appear in those colours. At the moment though, when I click on Blue in the top one, the bottom one also turns blue even if it says Red. How can I get the behaviour I'm looking for? I think I need to apply the JS to the whole class but I don't know how to do that but still keep them working separately and not interfering with the colouring of the other one. Also, I'd like to keep the hover behaviour I have where the text colour is retained and the background just goes slightly grayer even when hovering the mouse over. This can be seen in the JSFiddle below.

As a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xosgwvaj/)

HTML

```
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select">
    <option value="red" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select">
    <option value="red" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();   

  $("#select").selectpicker("refresh");
  $('.filter-option').css("color",$('#select').val());
   $('#select').on('change', function(){
    $('.filter-option').css('color', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: IDs needs to be unique, you have 2 `#select`, target them by using a class instead

Comment: I tried that but I still can't get it working. Are you able to do a JSFiddle fork to show me what you mean?

Comment: This works for me https://jsfiddle.net/xosgwvaj/1/

Comment: With that I am not seeing any colors when selected

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of - you have same id for both pickers. It should be different. Secondly, use $(this) in the on('change', function) to address only chosen select.

```
  $('.pickerSelectClass').change(function(){
   $(this).css('color', $(this).val());
  });
```

Above solves color switching upon actual "change" of select.
To also make sure colors are displayed correspondingly from the very beginning - add in this line:

```
$('.pickerSelectClass').each(function(){
    $(this).css('color', $(this).val());
});
```

To make this all look even more pretty:

```
$('.pickerSelectClass').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color', $(this).val());
}).change(function(){
   $(this).css('color', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Are you able to do a JSFiddle fork to show me what you mean?

Comment: sure gimme a sec

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much! I also realised I can have both inside the one selectContainer.

Comment: enjoy ;) yes, this code will not restrict your actions in playing around with number of options inside select and amount of selects of that same class - the code will cover it all thereon.

Comment: I've realised that your example breaks the hover behaviour that I want. In the example that I gave, when you hover over an option the text color doesn't change and the background just becomes slightly grayer. In your example it reverts back to the standard behaviour of the background turning blue and the text turning white, which is what I don't want.

Comment: it does seem to answer your question and this one seems to be a new issue not mentioned in the question, so if you could put it this way can help you look into this. Meanwhile, my example does not turn background property into blue and text to white.

Comment: you also don't usually mark question answered and then once you had a follow-up question not mentioned in your initial request, you just unmark the answer you have yourself accepted - won't get you far with people answering your questions

Comment: That's fair enough, I didn't mention that I wanted that in the original post. But that behaviour was present in the JSFiddle I posted and with your code it does change the background property into blue and text to white, just look at this JSF https://jsfiddle.net/gcd29fne/2/

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the JSF I originally posted, because it uses bootstrap-select to avoid that default hover behaviour, it refers to ".filter-option", which I'm guessing is bootstrap-select specific class. Your example refers to $(this), so I'm guessing it only affects the default select behaviour and not the bootstrap behaviour.

Comment: I've reaccepted your answer because you were basically answering what I asked for and someone else has answered the question in another thread. So thanks for the help and sorry for messing you around.

Comment: thanks man, let me know if you need further help though. Was away last day so just now saw your comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this js

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();   

    var pickers = $(".pickerSelectClass");
  for(var i = 0; i<pickers.length; i++){
    var id = pickers[i].id;
    $("#select-"+id).selectpicker("refresh");
    $('.filter-option').css("color",$('#select').val());
     $('#select-'+id).on('change', function(){
      $('.filter-option').css('color', $(this).val());
    }); 
  }

});
```

And this html

```
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select-2">
    <option value="red" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="selectContainer">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="select-1">
    <option value="red" style="color:red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue" style="color:blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Just adding a unique id for each picker, and applying the same logic, but in separate threads (moments)

Comment: `$('#select').on` there is no `#select` anymore

Comment: Why not? Yes there is... I kept it, now it is #select-[id]

Comment: yes you changed it to `#select-[id]` so where is `#select` in `$('#select').on('change', function(){` this is part of your solution code

Comment: You're right, my bad. Thank you! I edited the solution, eventhough the other answer was even better than mine

Comment: Hi Uriel, I tried your solution with #select-[id] but it still won't work. Are you able to do a JSFiddle with it working?

Comment: Wasn't @Zerus answer succesful?